# parsing a jsonArray in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I have this jsonArray in a file in python. I want to parse this and retrieve information such as orders, number, vendornumber and so on. How do I do that?
How to parse a jsonArray in python?

```
(
        [count] => 1
        [total] => 1
        [orders] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [number] => 613
                        [vendorNumber] => 613
                        [created] => 2015-09-29 02:01:51
                        [paymentStatus] => ACCEPTED
                        [fulfillmentStatus] => NEW
                        [billingPerson] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Farhaan
                                [companyName] => 
                                [street] => belapur
    Navi
                                [city] => Mumbai
                                [countryCode] => IN
                                [postalCode] => 
                                [stateOrProvinceCode] => 15
                                [stateName] => 15
                                [countryName] => India
                                [phone] => 
                            )

                        [paymentParameters] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [customerName] => xyz
                        [customerEmail] => xyz@gmail.com
                        [customerIP] => 182.70.60.203
                        [customerCountryCodeByIP] => IN
                        [subtotalCost] => 0
                        [couponDiscountCost] => 0
                        [volumeDiscountCost] => 0
                        [discountCost] => 0
                        [shippingCost] => 0
                        [taxCost] => 0
                        [totalCost] => 0
                        [items] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [sku] => Dummy-HCm-8
                                        [name] => Dummy HCm 8
                                        [quantity] => 1
                                        [price] => 0
                                        [weight] => 0
                                        [productId] => 0
                                        [options] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Access  option
                                                        [type] => SELECT
                                                        [value] => Self Paced Only
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [categoryId] => 0
                                        [taxes] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [lastChangeDate] => 2018-08-25 23:24:00
                        [updated] => 2018-08-25 23:24:00
                        [sample] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```

I have written a small piece of code for the same but unfortunately that is not working. The code is as follows:

```
import json


input_file = open('data/data2')
json_array = json.loads(input_file.read())
store_list = []

for item in json_array:
    store_details = {"number":None, "name":None}
    store_details['number'] = item['number']
    store_details['name'] = item['name']
    store_list.append(store_details)

print(store_list)
```

Comment: The file you are showing is clearly no valid json. It looks like an printed out php array.

Comment: So how do I parse that file in python. Is it possible?

Comment: It might be possible, but only with a self written token analyzer/parser and a lot of effort. Can you modify the output, so it prints out real json? Can you confirm this is a php array? You can convert a php array to json with `$json = json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: You might be able to use python's string replace method to replace all `[` and `] ` with `"`, `Array` with nothing, and parentheses with curly braces, and `=>` with `:`, and add commas in at the end of some lines.

Comment: One problem is that you cannot tell if a value is `0` or `"0"`.